# Can't scrape Bangood site with beautiful soup and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi guys i found some problems in using Beautiful Soup.
I'm trying to scrape Bangood's Website, but, I don't know why, i've only succedeed in scraping item's name.
Using selenium I scraped Item's Price (only un USD not in euros)
So I ask for your help, I would be so pleased if you knew any way to overcome these problems.

I would like to scrape Name, Price in Euros, Discount, Stars, Image, but I cannot understand why Beautiful soup doesn't work.

Ps. Obviously I don't want all the functions but the reason why beautiful soup give all these problems and an example if you can.

Now I'm trying to post here the html I want to scrape (in beautiful soup if possible).

Thanks for all!

The link i wanna scrape = https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA

```
<span class="main-price" oriprice-range="0-0" oriprice="22.99">19,48€</span>

<strong class="average-num">4.95</strong>



 <img src="https://imgaz1.staticbg.com/thumb/large/oaupload/banggood/images/1B/ED/b3e9fd47-ebb4-479b-bda2-5979c9e03a11.jpg.webp" id="landingImage" data-large="https://imgaz1.staticbg.com/thumb/large/oaupload/banggood/images/1B/ED/b3e9fd47-ebb4-479b-bda2-5979c9e03a11.jpg" dpid="left_largerView_image_180411|product|18101211554" data-src="https://imgaz1.staticbg.com/thumb/large/oaupload/banggood/images/1B/ED/b3e9fd47-ebb4-479b-bda2-5979c9e03a11.jpg" style="height: 100%; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
```

These are the functions i'm using

This doesn't work:

```
def take_image_bang(soup):   #beautiful soup and json

    img_div = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":'product-image'})

    imgs_str = img_div.img.get('data-large')  # a string in Json format

    # convert to a dictionary
    imgs_dict = json.loads(imgs_str)
    print(imgs_dict)
    #each key in the dictionary is a link of an image, and the value shows the size (print all the dictionay to inspect)
    #num_element = 0 
    #first_link = list(imgs_dict.keys())[num_element]
    return imgs_dict
```

These work (but only USD not Euros for the function get_price):

```
def get_title_bang(soup): #beautiful soup
     
    try:
        # Outer Tag Object
        title = soup.find("span", attrs={"class":'product-title-text'})
 
        # Inner NavigableString Object
        title_value = title.string
 
        # Title as a string value
        title_string = title_value.strip()
 
        # # Printing types of values for efficient understanding
        # print(type(title))
        # print(type(title_value))
        # print(type(title_string))
        # print()
 
    except AttributeError:
        title_string = ""   
 
    return title_string

def get_Bangood_price(driver):  #selenium

    c = CurrencyConverter()

    prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('main-price')
    
    
    for price in prices:

        price = price.text.replace("US$","")
        priceZ = float(price)
        
        
        price_EUR = c.convert(priceZ, 'USD', 'EUR')

    return price_EUR
```

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: [This is the link](https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want price in EUR url needs be change you can set accoriding from web page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA&DCC=IT&currency=EUR",headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
```

Finding title:

```
main_div=soup.find("div",class_="product-info")
title=main_div.find("h1",class_="product-title").get_text(strip=True)
print(title)
```

Output:

```
ANENG AN8008 Vero RMS Digitale Multimetri Tester di AC DC Corrente Tensione Resistenza Frenquenza CapacitàCOD
```

For findign reviews:

```
star=[i.get_text(strip=True) for i in main_div.find("div",class_="product-reviewer").find_all("dd")]
star
```

Output:

```
['5 Stella2618 (95.8%)',
 '4 Stella105 (3.8%)',
 '3 Stella9 (0.3%)',
 '2 Stella0 (0.0%)',
 '1 Stella2 (0.1%)']
```

finding price and other you can get from `script` tag use `json` to load it!

```
data=soup.find("script", attrs={"type":"application/ld+json"}).string.strip().strip(";")
import json
main_data=json.loads(data)
```

finding values from it:

```
price=main_data['offers']['priceCurrency']+" "+main_data['offers']['price']
image=main_data['image']
print(price,image)
```

Output:

```
EUR 19.48 https://imgaz3.staticbg.com/thumb/view/oaupload/banggood/images/1B/ED/b3e9fd47-ebb4-479b-bda2-5979c9e03a11.jpg
```

> for finding discount price as prices are update dynamically you can
> use xhr link to call and find data from it! here is the
>
> [url](https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/t?anno=3&client=te_lib&format=html&v=1.0&key=AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw&logld=vTE_20210503_00&sl=it&tl=en&tc=1&dom=1&sr=1&tk=736161.909205&mode=1)
> use post request for it!

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the data in euros, you need to change your link address and add this to the end of the link:

- For EURO add:  *&currency=EUR*
- For USD  add:  *&currency=USD*

For Euro the link should be :
https://it.banggood.com/ANENG-AN8008-True-RMS-Wave-Output-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Current-Volt-Resistance-Frequency-Capacitance-Test-p-1157985.html?rmmds=flashdeals&cur_warehouse=USA&currency=EUR

For another example: if you wish to change the warehouse for the product change:

- For CN change:   *cur_warehouse=CN*
- For USA change:  *cur_warehouse=USA*
- For PL change:   *cur_warehouse=PL*

These are dynamic variables for a URL that changes the webpage depending on their inputs.

After this, your second method should work just fine. Happy **scraping**!!!